# Cannot convert label value from string to int. Result is always equal to 0

Tags: c#, winforms

Main.cs contains variables and (as User Control) buttons, to increase value of variables.
Form1.cs is a primary Form, with methods and timers. 
Graph.cs is only to draw form.

Main.cs

```cs
private int money;
private int income;

 public string MoneyLabel
 {
    get { return moneyLabel.Text; }
    set { moneyLabel.Text = value; }
 }
```

Form1.cs

```cs
public Main start = new Main(100, 40, 0, 0);
...
start.Money += start.Income;
...
main1.MoneyLabel = start.Money.ToString();
...
```

Everything works fine here. Now I am trying to convert value, from moneyLabel with property MoneyLabel, and put it on graph.

Graph.cs

```cs
Main main1 = new Main();
...
 if (int.TryParse(main1.MoneyLabel, out a))
 {
    throw new Exception(main1.MoneyLabel);
 }
```

That exception provides message with "0" value.
MoneyLabel is increasing every second with integer, but I am not able to convert that value back. 
It always gives 0 as result. 
I tried with multiple convert declarations: Parse, TryParse, Convert.ToInt32 etc.

Full code: https://github.com/aescaesse/Csharp-codes/tree/master/firsttry

Comment: In your `Graph` user control, you create a new instance of `Main`. This is not the same instance of main that you're changing the values on from `Form1`. So, it'll always have the initial value of 0. You need to pass the instance of `Main` from `Form1` to the `Graph`.

Comment: Can you share minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: You seem to be creating a *new* Main where you should use the existing one

Comment: `start.Money += start.Income;` - You have not defined these properties in `Main`. Please at least take the time to post correct code; otherwise, we are debugging your typos.

Comment: Have you tried `decimal.TryParse()` if the value in the label is displayed as money? Please give us an example of the contents of the label (`.Text` property) so we can understand what is going on here and we can test our code.

Comment: @JonathanWood I think that's a bit harsh, they are defined in the full code repo provided.

Comment: @steve16351: Well, if that's how you feel you can post questions on stackoverflow that people trying to help need to figure out. For me, I'll try to post actual code that is failing and will continue to urge others to do the same.

Comment: @steve16351 I just can't pass the instance so I made property to return it to another class and store in new variable. That seems to be fine but after using any property on new object, exception shows up `system.nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Form1.cs `public static Main Instance  {get { return start; }}`

Graph.cs `Main mainInstance = new Main();  mainInstance = Form1.Instance;`
and now `Console.WriteLine(mainInstance.MoneyLabel);` gives exception

Answer (score 0):

In the Form1 class at line 48 you should inject the main1 instance of Main at line47.
Then in the Economy class constructor you should inject it to the InitializeComponent which create a Graph instance at line 37 were you should inject the main instance.
Then you use the instance there instead of create a new Main instance and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your code correctly, MoneyValue property, returns the Text from Label, but I guess, when you increase Money property, you forgot to set the Text of Label as Money value. It should be handled in setter, or by using INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

Regards

Comment: This isn't correct, on the timer tick, `CalculateIncome` increases the integer money value, and then `ShowData` syncs the label with that value via the MoneyLabel property.